# Eloquent hasMany relationship get() not working for nested objects

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a case in which an object hasMany items, which hasMany items. For example, a `house` hasMany `rooms`, and each `room` hasMany `furnitures`.

In the past, it was as simple as saying:

```
$house->rooms()->get()->all();
```

And I would get all the objects with their nested objects in arrays (please excuse any errors in my JSON syntax):

```
{"house_name":"Max's House", "rooms":["den":[{"furniture_name":"couch"}],"kitchen":[{"furniture_name":"bed"}]]}, {.......}
```

But in another case, when I use the same style of code, it gets the `house` and `rooms`, but not the `furnitures` associated with the `room`objects. What could be the reason for this? My code seems to be the same in both cases in terms of relationship declarations in the classes:

```
 public function rooms() {
    return $this->hasMany('HouseRoom', 'house_id');
}
```

I know this isn't much to go on, but I am hoping to find someone who has experienced such an issue before.

My guesses are that:

- I don't know squat and how objects are returned with all of their properties
- There is a foreign key problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a classic syntax error on how to get the data. In order to get an object and all of its child objects, assuming the relationships are properly setup, you need to use:

```
$house->rooms;
```